# Constructor initializer does not allow me to use 'this'

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Compiler Error
    Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

```
delegate void CallBack(int i);
class A
{
    public A(CallBack cb) { }
}
class B : A
{        
    public B() : base(new CallBack(this.f)){}

    private void f(int i) { }
}
```

Why is this error ?
As a solution I thought of providing a parameterless protected ctor in A() and have

```
class B : A
{
     public B() : base()   // inherit the new A() ctor
     {
          base.cb = new CallBack(this.f); //this is allowed here
     }
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because "this" hasn't been created until the base class constructor has run.
In your 2nd example the base constructor has finished, and now "this" has meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the B instance is not initialized yet. In the second, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the object is not yet (fully) constructed, that is the base constructor was not yet run, `this` is not available there.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a abstract/virtual method.

```
abstract class A {
    A() {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    abstract void Initialize() { }
}

class B : A {
    string Text;

    B() { }

    override void Initialize() {
        this.Text = "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're actually recommending calling a virtual method from a constructor??

Comment: This may be a nice pattern to follow, but "Text" should be in A because as you can see in my pb, A also inits the callback,
and also the solution that I gave uses ctors only (no initialisers, so no confusion for the user). However thx 4 solution.

Comment: @Greg: Yes, this is one of possible solution.

@cataounfeldeszuzieq: The "Text" can be in A or B, it's not important. The source code was only sample of one of possible situations.

@unknown: Please tell me, why I got a negative point. It will be usefull for me and others. Thanks.